# How to perform multiple instantiation of a fragment extending YouTubePlayerSupportFragment class?

Tags: android-youtube-api

I have two fragments in my main Activity.
Each fragment should play different youtube video.
But In my code,both the fragments are playing same video although I passes different url to the two instances of YouTubePlayerSupportFragment class.

MainActivity-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    VideoFragment f1=VideoFragment.newInstance("kXYiU_JCYtU");

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container1, f1).commit();
    VideoFragment f2 =  new VideoFragment();
    f2=VideoFragment.newInstance("k4V3Mo61fJM");
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container2, f2).commit();
}
```

activity_main.xml-

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    >
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragment_container1"
    >
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

VideoFragment class-

```
public VideoFragment() { }

public static VideoFragment newInstance(String url) {

    VideoFragment f = new VideoFragment();

    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("url", url);

    f.setArguments(b);
    f.init();

    return f;
}

private void init() {

    initialize("AIzaSyDM2vaVDpwGGFEcQCcD_hA38ZQo2Tqa06o", new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {



        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.cueVideo(getArguments().getString("url"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }


    });
}
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible. Youtube player based on singletone patern, so every time you will get same player